# AWS Glue Context does not support sql query

Tags: python, apache-spark, aws-glue

Use Case: Pass a query with a where clause in AWS glue.

```
source_df = glueContext.read.format("jdbc")
  .option("url","jdbc:oracle:thin://@xxxxx:1521/ORCL")
  .option("user","user")
  .option("password","password")
  .option("dbtable","(Select * from test) as test")
  .option("driver","oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
  .load()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/comments_jdbc", line 17, in <module> source_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:oracle:thin://xxxxx:1521/ORCL").option("user","user").option("password","password").option("dbtable","(Select * from test) as test").option("driver","oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").load()

File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load return self._df(self._jreader.load())

File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__ answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)

File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco return f(*a, **kw)

File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value format(target_id, ".", name), value) 

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o77.load. : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended at 

oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) at 

oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) at 

oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951) at 

oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513) at 

oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227) at 

oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) at 

oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208) at 

oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886) at 

oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175) at
```

Answer (score 1):

this are 5 different code snippets that i tried for performance comparison, only 2 actually filtered data on the server level when using profiler, it seems at the moment without creating a custom connector or buying from marketplace the only way to get this to work is using **glueContext.read**

You can [convert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html) DynamicFrames to and from DataFrames ([See example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-medicaid.html))

```
rds_dynamicframe = DynamicFrame.fromDF(rds_dataframe, glueContext, "nested")
```

you should also check this while running **Sql Server Profiler** with all the events from: **OLEDB**, **Stored Procedure**, **TSQL** and **Transactions**

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.context import DynamicFrame

# list parameter with 2 leading hyphens --param_server_url 
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,['JOB_NAME'])
print("JOB_NAME: ", args['JOB_NAME'])

job_server_url="SERVER URL"
job_db_name="DB NAME"
job_db_user="DB USER"
job_db_password="DB PASSWORD"
job_table_name="TABLE NAME"

job_glue_db_name="GLUE DATA CATALOG DATABASE NAME"
job_glue_conn_name="GLUE DATA CATALOG CONNECTION NAME"
job_glue_table_name="GLUE DATA CATALOG TABLE NAME"

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
region = "us-east-1"

#### aws glue data catalog table info (from ) ####
# Name  job_glue_table_name
# Database  job_glue_db_name
# Classification    sqlserver
# Location  job_db_name.dbo.job_table_name
# Connection    job_glue_conn_name

#### GlueContext Class ####
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html

#### DynamicFrame Class ####
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html

#### Connection Api ####
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_Connection.html

#### Using connectors and connections with AWS Glue Studio ####
# Link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/connectors-chapter.html
# Use AWS Secrets Manager for storing credentials
# Filtering the source data with row predicates and column projections 

#### Connection options for type custom.jdbc or marketplace.jdbc ####
# Link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-jdbc
# className – String, required, driver class name.
# connectionName – String, required, name of the connection that is associated with the connector.
# secretId or user/password – String, required, used to retrieve credentials for the URL.
# dbTable or query – String, required, the table or SQL query to get the data from. You can specify either dbTable or query, but not both.
# filterPredicate – String, optional, extra condition clause to filter data from source. For example:

# using \ for new line with more commands
# query="recordid<=5", -- filtering !
print("0001 - df_read_query")
df_read_query = glueContext.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://"+job_server_url+":1433;databaseName="+job_db_name+";") \
    .option("query","select recordid from "+job_table_name+" where recordid <= 5") \
    .option("user",job_db_user) \
    .option("password",job_db_password) \
    .load()
print("df_read_query count: ", df_read_query.count())
df_read_query.show(10)
df_read_query.printSchema()

# query="recordid<=5", -- not filtering
print("0002 - df_from_catalog_query")
df_from_catalog_query = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = job_glue_db_name, 
    table_name = job_glue_table_name, 
    additional_options={
        "query":"select recordid from "+job_table_name+" where recordid <= 5;",
    },
    transformation_ctx = "df_from_catalog_query", 
)
print("df_from_catalog_query count: ", df_from_catalog_query.count())
df_from_catalog_query.show(10)

# push_down_predicate="recordid<=5", -- not filtering
print("0003 - df_from_catalog_push_down_predicate")
df_from_catalog_push_down_predicate = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = job_glue_db_name, 
    table_name = job_db_name+'_dbo_'+job_table_name, 
    push_down_predicate = "recordid<=5",
    transformation_ctx = "df_from_catalog_push_down_predicate",
)
print("df_from_catalog_push_down_predicate count: ", df_from_catalog_push_down_predicate.count())
df_from_catalog_push_down_predicate.show(10)

# filterPredicate="recordid<=5", -- not filtering
print("0004 - df_from_options_sqlserver")
df_from_options_sqlserver = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type = "sqlserver", 
    connection_options = {
        "url":"jdbc:sqlserver://"+job_server_url+":1433;databaseName="+job_db_name+";",
        "username":job_db_user,
        "password":job_db_password,
        "location":job_db_name+".dbo."+job_table_name,
        "filterPredicate":"recordid<=5",
    }, 
    transformation_ctx = "df_from_options_sqlserver",
)
print("df_from_options_sqlserver count: ", df_from_options_sqlserver.count())
df_from_options_sqlserver.show(10)

# dbtable="recordid<=5", -- filtering !
print("0005 - df_read_dbtable")
df_read_dbtable = glueContext.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://"+job_server_url+":1433;databaseName="+job_db_name+";") \
    .option("user",job_db_user) \
    .option("password",job_db_password) \
    .option("dbtable","(select recordid from "+job_table_name+" where recordid<=5) as t1") \
    .option("driver","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .load()
print("df_read_dbtable count: ", df_read_dbtable.count())
df_read_dbtable.show(10)

job.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any where clause in your `option` for `dbtable` but I tried running the query directly in Oracle and it threw me the same error that you received. It looks like Oracle doesn't support table aliases and allows only for columns.

If you still want to use alias then try running below query from Glue job or just select query with out parentheses.

```
select test.* from (select * from test) test
```

Or simply run the query as it is with some where clause in it:

```
select * from test where <some_col=value>
```